# Several errors when indenting while creating class in C#

Tags: c#, class, methods

I am very new to C# as I have only started studying it in University in the last month so it is all very new to me. Coming over from C++ I am very out of place.
When creating a new class I keep running into these same errors in visual studio.
After typing

```
public int Credit(balance)
```

It won't automatically generate my {} and it un-indents my code? Any ideas?

[Screenshot of the issue is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tl1pK.png)

Comment: remove the semicolon from the method signature

Comment: Please post code, not images.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the parameter type on your parameter. A valid line would be:

```
public int Credit(int balance)
```

The invalid method declaration is probably why the extra help doesn't kick in.

Answer (score 1):

You didnt define the type of balance, for example

```
public int Credit(int balance)
```

I'm sure you have to do this in c++ too.